# mkdir(name, mode) OSError

Tags: python, error-handling, deep-learning

I  am trying to run the train.py code which is available online in the following link:

https://github.com/ethanfetaya/NRI

I could successfully generate the data, but when I run `python train.py`, it gives me the following error:

`mkdir(name, mode) OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: './logs/exp2020-07-30T10:21:59.679434/'`

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: There is no `logs` folder, so you need to create the `logs` folder which is the parent of `exp2020-07-30T10:21:59.679434` folder

Comment: or you could use `os.makedirs` instead of `os.mkdir`

Comment: @ArjunMuraleedharan The error does not say that the directory does not exist, it says the syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, no colon (the : char) is allowed in the filename.

Comment: So why downvoting please ? That's a perfectly valid answer.